# Do child routes require a default component

Tags: angular, angular-router

Simple question. As stated in the title.

Let's say I have additional data that I want to display but only accessible through the route. We'll say that the parent route is `data/:id` and the additional data route is `data/:id/extra-data`.

It looks like if I navigate to `data/:id/extra-data` then navigate to `data/:id` the component set to display on `data/:id/extra-data` is still visible.

Comment: The component that you registered the `data/:id` route to should have a `<router-outlet>` that will be used for child routes.

Comment: Can you at least show your current routing module/s for your described scenario?

Comment: No it's a simple question guys. Simple. Just answer it.

You don't need to see code. Just give me the answer.

And Edric, Yeah I got that.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is yes you do need a component for the default route. Otherwise a component for a child route will be visible even if you navigate from it.

God Stacked Overflow can be so dense sometimes.

```
{
path: 'data/:id',
component: DataComponent,
runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
children: [
//  This is the default route. Without it other childroutes stay rendered when navigated to
  {
    path: '', 
    component: DumbComponent,
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
  },
 {
    path: 'extra-data',
    component: ExtraDataComponent,
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
  },
],
```

Again this wasn’t a code question. But apparently everyone needs to see code.

Comment: This is more of a framework question than a code question. That's why I'm frustrated over requests for code here. But any why here you go.